How to type hint a class method from class annotations
I have a parent class Foo implementing a classmethod. I'd like to allow subclasses of Foo to specify variables as annotations and specify that this subclass classmethod should be called with keyword only arguments that match its annotations (like we can do with dataclasses constructor whose constructor only allows class annotations members as parameters). I don't mean to do any runtime check, this is just a matter of type hinting so that my type checker warn me when I call this method with an argument that is not in the class annotations. For example
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls, **kwargs) -> None:
        # Some implementation 
        pass


class Child(Foo):
    valueA: int
    valueB: str

Is there any way to specify to type checker that Child.my_classmethod should only accept as key word parameters valueA and valueB and nothing else ? I know i could just change the signature of my_class_method manually for each subclass but I have many of those and I have several methods that should only accept class annotations as key words parameters.. Is there any way to accomplish that ?
I did try to accomplish that by subclassing dataclasses.dataclass but I was not able to make it work since it only type hint the constructor
I also tried to do some tricks with typing.Literal and the class annotations but it did not work either

What is a use case for this? Why would the base class accept keyword arguments related to the child class? How would it know what to do with those keywords?

@Barmar This is about sql and database. The child class annotations represent table columns and these classmethods are used to interact with the table (insert, searching...). That's why the keyword args have to be in the table columns, searching data in non existing column would throw an error anyway but I was wondering if there is a way to spot it while coding

no, but typically, you coul just make my_class_method accept an instance of Child

Only mypy plugin is an option here, you can't express this in python's type system alone. You may want to see what django-stubs do for that (specifically typing of django.db.models.QuerySet and corresponding plugin parts).
